# casperjs login form error

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I am using this code to login to form. I get error.

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

var url = "www.example.com";


 casper.start(url,function(){
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.waitForResource(url,function() {
    this.fillSelectors("form[method='post']", {
        'input[name="userName"]' : 'usr1',
        'input[name="password"]': 'pswed1'
    }, true);
});

casper.run();
```

http://prntscr.com/7jkia1

I pretty much copied examples I found on stack but still I get error... what to do to fix this?

Comment: its telling you it cannot find the form...

Comment: I got that but I tried over and over again... no reason why...

Comment: Are you sure that you're on the correct page? Have you taken a screenshot to check (`casper.capture()`)? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: Please add the protocol to the url. For example: `http://example.com`. As I said before, PhantomJS is pretty picky about the URL.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that casper is not able to do a selector for form[method='post'] ( using fillSelectors ), its not working for me either. But if you specify any other atribute like name, id, class, enctype, action, etc, it works.

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

var url = "https://careershub.bbc.co.uk/members/";

 casper.start(url,function(){
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.waitForResource(url,function() {
    this.fillSelectors('form#registration-form', {
        'input[name="name_first"]' : 'firstname',
        'input[name="name_last"]': 'lastname'
    }, true);

    this.captureSelector('test.png', 'form');
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: I tried this code and got the error. http://prntscr.com/7jl8x5 
When I went to line 802 in casper.js file I got this. http://prntscr.com/7jl9bb

Comment: @macroscripts dont know why you're getting that error, works flawlessly here ( http://i.imgur.com/gctDw1Q.png, the two inputs get filled correctly ). Maybe try reinstalling casperjs and phantomjs.

Comment: @macroscripts i noticed your console isn't even printing out the page title. Are you behind a proxy or something ? seems like you're not even being able to connect to the website properly.